# simple global planner (problem planner_frequency)

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am trying to implement an extremely simple global planner (tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Writing%20A%20Global%20Path%20Planner%20As%20Plugin%20in%20ROS), it will create just a straight line between the "start" and "goal" points. However, I want this trajectory to be static, so I set the planner_frequency parameter to 0.0, but move_base continues to recreate the trajectory. Am I forgetting to implement something?

my global planner:

```
 #include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>
 #include "planejador_header.h"

 //register this planner as a BaseGlobalPlanner plugin
 PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(planejador::Planejador, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)

 using namespace std;

 //Default Constructor
 namespace planejador {

 Planejador::Planejador (){

 }

 Planejador::Planejador(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){
   initialize(name, costmap_ros);
 }


 void Planejador::initialize(std::string name, costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS* costmap_ros){

 }

 bool Planejador::makePlan(const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& start, const geometry_msgs::PoseStamped& goal,  std::vector<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>& plan ){
    

   plan.push_back(start);
   
   plan.push_back(goal);

  return true;
 }
 };
```

Demonstrative video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nigHifk89Y&feature=youtu.be

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355623/simple-global-planner-(problem-planner_frequency)/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

it is necessary to have more reference points between the "start" and "goal" points if the distance to be covered is greater than 1m

---

Originally posted by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) with karma: 125 on 2020-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0